# Lexing/tokenization delimited strings

Tags: tokenize, lexer

I'm writing a hand-written lexer for a small language but have one weird requirement that I'm not sure how to handle.

I need to be able to support the notion of delimited strings where the delimiter could be any char. eg. strings are most likely to be delimited using double quotes (eg. `"hello"`) but it could just as easily be `/hello/` or `,hello,`

eg. some sample input lines might be:

```
x = /abc/
y = "abc" + ,def,
z = zabcz
```

The last case is a bit pathological, but technically possible.

I'm trying work out if there's any way I can do this in the tokenization phase in the general case? Any thoughts or suggestions would be grand.

Answer (score 0):

Here are solutions in c++ and js.

c++

```
#include "vector"
#include "string"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
// Lexically Analyze method
auto lex_argument(string code){
// Define variables
size_t equal_location;
int counter = 0;
auto variable;
string variable_name;
auto variable_info[2]
string code_for_inspection;
/* In the case of a variable , these two characters will hold the beginning and end of the string */
char string_variable_characters[2];
equal_location = code.find("=",0,code.length());
variable_value = code.substr(equal_location + 2,code.length());
variable_name = code.substr(code.begin(),equal_location - 2);
variable_info[0] = variable_name;
string_variable_characters[0] = (char) variable_value.substr(0,1);
string_variable_characters[1] = (char) 
variable_value.substr(variable_value.length() - 1,variable_value.length());
if(string_variable_charecters[0] = string_variable_charecters[1]){
variable_name.erase(0,1);
variable_value.erase(variable_value.length() - 1,variable_value.length());
variable_info[1] = variable_value;
}
return variable_info;
}
```

and in js:

```
function lex_argument(code){
var equalLocation = code.search("=");
var variableInfo = [null,null];
variableInfo[1] = code.substr(1,equalLocation - 2);
variableInfo[0] = code.substr(equalLocation,code.length);
string_delimeters = [variableInfo[0].substr(1,2),variableInfo[0].substr(variableInfo[0].length - 1,variableInfo[0].length];
return variableInfo;
}
```